# How to avoid notification email send out when update users' profile

Tags: user-profile-property, mysite, notifications

We are using SP2013 on-premise enterprise edition. Recently we need to batch update 5000+ users' profile by import a CSV with PowerShell.

When I test the script, I found the update is being treated as "update" regardless the value. For instance, if user A followed user B, user A will receive an email like "user B's position is changed from manager to manager"

Is there any way to get rid of it?